# frequencies in Julia's real FFT

Tags: julia, fft, fftw

I'm using Julia's FFT implementation to perform a 2D real FFT on a couple of arrays but I can't be sure of the order of the frequencies in the output. Consider the MWE

```
N=64
U = rand(Float64, N, N);

FFTW.set_num_threads(2)
prfor = plan_rfft(U, (1,2), flags=FFTW.MEASURE);

size(prfor*U)
```

The output is an array of size `(33, 64)`.

Julia doesn't have a `rfftfreq` function like Numpy does, and the fact that Julia's output is different from Numpy's `fft.rfftn` default output makes me not want to use Numpy's default here. I read the documentation but it's not clear how the frequencies are organized just by reading that.

Is there anywhere that tells us the order of the frequencies?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are seeking exactly, but if you use DSP.jl, its util.jl file probably has what you may need:

https://github.com/JuliaDSP/DSP.jl/blob/master/src/util.jl

```
"""
    rfftfreq(n, fs=1)
Return discrete fourier transform sample frequencies for use with
`rfft`. The returned Frequencies object is an AbstractVector
containing the frequency bin centers at every sample point. `fs`
is the sample rate of the input signal.
"""
```